# Sort entities by HashMap field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the entity, which contains a Map field. I need to sort entities by map values. I use Spring-Data repositories. So I pass PageRequest object with sort list to findAll repository method. Unfortunately sorting for the Map field returns error that property is undefined (it works for all other fields) - I tired 'additionalData', 'additionalData.key', 'additionalData.value'. What mapping should I use?

```
class Employee{
  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column
  private String lastName;

  @ElementCollection
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @CollectionTable(name="ADDITIONALDATA", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name="Key")
  @Column(name="Value")
  private Map<String, String> additionalData;
}

Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "additionalData");
Sort sort = new Sort(order);
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 20, sort);
employeeRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
```

Comment: No idea what that means "sort entities by map values". A map has multiple values. Sort how???? A Map is not a single column. It is multiple rows in a join table.

Comment: For example I'd like to sort entities by the values where the key is 'xzy'. Is it somehow possible?